# How can I hide column when range is shown (not hidden) in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm looking for a way that will hide row "I" if range: QTYCALCON is shown.

So far I came up with this.

```
Sub Hide_Show()
 With Range("QTYCALCON").EntireColumn
  .Hidden = Not .Hidden
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing and lacks detail. You state you want to hide a row, but your title and code refer to column. Please [edit] your question to clarify. Is "QTYCALCON" a column heading, named range or a table?

Answer (score 0):

That should be rather posted in Stack Overflow. However, here it goes for hiding **column** `I`:

```
Sub Hide_Show()
With Range("QTYCALCON").EntireColumn
    If Not .Hidden Then
        Range("I:I").EntireColumn.Hidden= True
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This hides both columns if `.Hidden` is TRUE. I believe they want "I" hidden if "QTYCALCON" is not.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you right... so, small correction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assumed "I" was a column and you want the code to work both ways depending on which column is hidden. So, here is the code I would use.

```
Sub Hide_Show()
    If Range("QTYCALCON").EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
        Columns("I").Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("QTYCALCON").EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
        Columns("I").Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Each time you run it, it will check to see if "QTYCALCON" is hidden. If not, it will hide "I". If "QTYCALCON" is hidden, this will unhide "I".